# Order by with distinct has an impact on performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have .6 million data set. Now I am trying to sort the data set by timestamp, and also due to one to many relationship I have to do some Inner JOIN and use distinct.

My Query is like below,

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, s.subject, p.joining_time
       FROM profile p
       INNER JOIN profile_subject ps ON p.id=ps.profile_id
       LEFT JOIN subject s ON ps.subject_id=s.id
       ORDER BY p.joining_time LIMIT 20;
```

Now this query is taking almost 28 sec
But without order by clause its taking only 0.11 sec

How to improve this query with desired result?

Comment: yes its already indexed.

Comment: Do you have a composite index or just an index on joining_time?

Comment: Binary index on joining_time. But what is the need of composite index here?

Comment: Show both `EXPLAIN` results please.

Comment: A couple of historical answers here suggest using a composite index, as MySQL *was* limited to utilising a single index per query, but that's been changed in more recent versions.

Comment: One index per table.  So 3 indexes are likely to be involved in this query.

Comment: Assuming `id` is the PRIMARY KEY of each table, `ps.profile_id` is the only additional INDEX needed for the JOINs.

Comment: `INDEX(joining_time)`, plus getting rid of the useless(?) DISTINCT is you best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simplest suggestion is to put an index on `profile(joining_time)`.  Then select a certain number of the most recent in a subquery.  For instance, if you are pretty confident that the top 20 rows you want are within the most recent 100 records in `profile`, then you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, s.subject, p.joining_time
FROM (SELECT p.id, p.joining_join
      FROM profile p
      ORDER BY p.joining_time
      LIMIT 100
     ) p INNER JOIN
     profile_subject ps
     ON p.id = ps.profile_id LEFT JOIN
     subject s
     ON ps.subject_id = s.id
ORDER BY p.joining_time
LIMIT 20;
```

I would also suggest that you remove the `DISTINCT` keyword.  Unless you have duplicate subjects for one profile, then this is not necessary.  Similarly, it is hard to believe that the `LEFT JOIN` is necessary.  In a well-structured database, there would be no `subject_id` values in `profile_subject` that are not in `subject`.  So, try this:

```
SELECT p.id, s.subject, p.joining_time
FROM (SELECT p.id, p.joining_join
      FROM profile p
      ORDER BY p.joining_time
      LIMIT 100
     ) p INNER JOIN
     profile_subject ps
     ON p.id = ps.profile_id JOIN
     subject s
     ON ps.subject_id = s.id
ORDER BY p.joining_time
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Yes I do have duplicate values. Between distinct and group by what should I use in case of duplicate values ?

Comment: @JohnMaclein . . . They should have very similar performance.  Most database engines use the same underlying algorithm for both.